# hitTestObject not hitTesting with all MovieClips

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, for-loop, hittest

Hey guys having a little trouble this might be easier than i am making it out to be. 
But the problem that i am having is when i hittest my mcPoints with my mcPlayer it is only interacting with 4 out of 5 of the movie clips that are added to the stage by a for loop.

I have been struggling with this for the past two days and cant seem to pin point the problem, everything seems set up perfectly but maybe you can help.

These are my Variables:

```
public var mcPoints:smallGainPoints;
    private var nPoints:Number = 5;
    private var aPointsArray:Array;
```

Here is how i set up the 5 mcPoints Movie Clips to be added to stage:

```
private function addPointsToStage():void
    {
         var startPoint:Point = new Point((stage.stageWidth / 2) - 100, stage.stageHeight / 2);
         var spacing:Number = 50;

         for (var i = 0; i < nPoints; i++)
         {
             trace(aPointsArray.length);
             mcPoints = new smallGainPoints();
             aPointsArray.push(mcPoints);
             stage.addChild(mcPoints);
             mcPoints.x = startPoint.x + (spacing * i);
             mcPoints.y = startPoint.y;
         }

    }
```

So that adds the 5 points movie Clips to the stage which are aligned horizontally.

And finally here is the loop that listens for the HitTestObject to Initiate:

```
private function checkPlayerHitPoints():void 
    {

        for (var i:int = 0; i < aPointsArray.length; i++)
            {
                //get current point in i loop
                var currentPoints:smallGainPoints = aPointsArray[i];

                //test if  player is hitting current point
                if(player.hitTestObject(currentPoints))
                {
                    //Add points sound effects
                    var pointsSound:Sound = new pointsPickUpSound();
                    pointsSound.play();

                    //remove point on stage
                    currentPoints.destroyPoints()
                    //remove points from array
                    aPointsArray.splice(i, 1);
                    trace(aPointsArray.length);

                    //Add plus 5 text to current points position
                    mcPlus5 = new plusFiveText();
                    stage.addChild(mcPlus5);
                    mcPlus5.x = (currentPoints.x);
                    mcPlus5.y = (currentPoints.y);

                    //Update high score text
                    nScore += 5;
                    updateHighScore();


                }

            }
    }
```

So i added traces both for when the movie clips are added and when they are hit here are the values i get:

0
1
2
3
4
Hit:  4
Hit:  3
Hit:  2
Hit:  1

Also i call the addPointsToStage(); in my constructor for more information.

So from the values im getting it seems that the last value "0" isn't being interacted with, any ideas why?   Please anything would be of use. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

i'm not exactly sure what your code is suppose to be doing. But when you remove element from array in loop you are lose one item.

You array is
`[1][2][3][4][5]`
When i=1 you remove element and get
`[1][3][4][5]`
next interation i=2 which means you never test agains value 3.

You should decrement i whenever you remove element from an array.

Comment: Sorry maybe i wasn't detailed enough. But the first part of the code as stated above just adds 5 movie clips to the stage. The second part of the code which is the hitTest checks if the movie clip "player" is coming in contact with all 5 of the movie clips called "points" But it is only hitting 4 out of 5 of the movie clips and not all 5 of them

Comment: Where would i decrement it at? I try that but still doesn't do anything

Comment: This is weird whenever i change the var Spacing to a different value the hittest works like when i change it to var Spacing:Number = 70; it works fine. but when its on 50 or any other value it doesnt work